# img tag removing slashes from the src

Tags: javascript, html

the problem I'm facing is that I get a image URL from an input tag then storing it in a let then I create a li tag with an image tag in it. I put `imageURL` variable in the `src` but the image tag removes the slashes from the variable

```
function addMovie(title, imageURL, rating){
    const li = document.createElement("li")
    const ul = document.getElementById("movie-list")
    li.className = "movie-element"
    li.innerHTML = `
    <div class="movie-element__image>
        <img src="${imageURL}" alt="${title}" id="img" height="100" width = "100">
    </div>
    <div class="movie-elements__info">
        <h2>
            ${title}
        </h2>
        <p>
            ${rating}/5 rating
        </p>
    </div>
    `
    ul.append(li);
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code as a snippet rather than images?

Comment: Please post your code as a text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `\` has special meaning. So you need to use `\\` instead of `\`  like this:

```
addMovie("test", "images\\test\\test.jpg" , 12)
```

```js
        function addMovie(title, imageURL, rating) {
            const li = document.createElement("li")
            const ul = document.getElementById("movie-list")
            li.className = "movie-element"
            li.innerHTML = `
    <div class="movie-element__image">
        <img src="${imageURL}" alt="${title}" id="img" height="100" width = "100">
    </div>
    <div class="movie-elements__info">
        <h2>
            ${title}
        </h2>
        <p>
            ${rating}/5 rating
        </p>
    </div>
    `
            ul.append(li);
        }

addMovie("test", "images\\test\\test.jpg" , 12)
```

```html
<ul id="movie-list"></ul>
```

Also you forgot `"` after `movie-element__image` class

Comment: @Sayiddygames I mentioned you have two problems first you forgot `"` and then `\\` is scape character. look at my snippet it works correctly

Answer (score 3):

you forgot an `"` after the div's class.

```
function addMovie(title, imageURL, rating){
    const li = document.createElement("li")
    const ul = document.getElementById("movie-list")
    li.className = "movie-element"
    li.innerHTML = `
    <div class="movie-element__image">
        <img src="${imageURL}" alt="${title}" id="img" height="100" width = "100">
    </div>
    <div class="movie-elements__info">
        <h2>
            ${title}
        </h2>
        <p>
            ${rating}/5 rating
        </p>
    </div>
    `
    ul.append(li);
}
```